# Counting stacked polygons in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, polygon, sql, overlapping-features, count

In my data set I have cases where I have multiple polygons stacked upon top of each other. I assume that those polygons have equal geometries but since there are a lot of them I am not sure 100%. Data is in a PostGIS database.

I am looking for PostGIS solution for counting those polygons inside procedure.

For now I came up with this but it looks like it takes too much time. I join polygons to the same data set and I use current_record to set id of polygon data set.

```sql
select count(*) into stacked_count from polygons p1
join polygons p2
on st_equals(current_record.wkb_geometry, p2.wkb_geometry)
where p1.ogc_fid=current_record.ogc_fid;
```

In a procedure I loop over every polygon and I do some calculations, so every current_record is a defined as `%ROWTYPE` of the polygon dataset.

Comment: If you expect them to be (binary) equal, you could `SELECT geom, COUNT(*) FROM ... GROUP BY geom;`

Comment: Does this table already have a spatial index? That would speed things up.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume there is a polygon layer called *'poly_test'*, see image below.

[image: input]

Extending the idea from @geozelot it is possible to count the polygons via grouping by their geometry.

With the following expression:

```sql
SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT("id") AS ids,
    GROUP_CONCAT("uniqueID") AS uniques,
    COUNT(*) AS NumGeom, -- COUNT(*)
    geometry AS geom
FROM
    "poly_test"
GROUP BY
    geometry
```

it is possible to get this output:

[image: output]

Alternatively, apply the query, that implies the [`ST_AsBinary()`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsBinary.html) function, however, can be also used with the [`ST_AsText()`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsText.html):

```sql
SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT("id") AS ids,
    GROUP_CONCAT("uniqueID") AS uniques,
    COUNT(ST_AsBinary(geometry)) AS BinGeom, -- COUNT(*)
    geometry AS geom
FROM
    "poly_test"
GROUP BY
    ST_AsBinary(geometry)
```

---

**References:**

- [Is it ok to group by geometry in PostGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/254885/is-it-ok-to-group-by-geometry-in-postgis)
- [One-to-many spatial join with results in one row in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/354187/one-to-many-spatial-join-with-results-in-one-row-in-qgis)